# How to pass multiple arguments to a newly created process in C# .net?

Tags: c#

How can I pass multiple arguments to a newly created process in C#?

Also which class (`Process` or `ProcessStartInfo` or `MyProcess`) in should I use in executing a program, with the condition of passing multiple arguments to the newly created/executed process?

As is I have the equivalent (Borland) C++ code for the same task, which is as follows:

```
spawnv(P_NOWAITO,Registry->ReadString("Downloader").c_str(),arglist);
```

where `arglist` is a char pointer array and
`Registry->ReadString("Downloader").c_str()`, is the program to execute.

Comment: Note that you do not pass arguments to newly-created processes. You pass arguments when the process is being created. Once the process has been created, the arguments are set.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to pass multiple command line arguments you should separate each with a space and surround it in quotes in case the argument itself contains a space.

```
string[] args = { "first", "second", "\"third arg\"" };
Process.Start("blah.exe", String.Join(" ", args));
```

Comment: Another alternative is to set ProcessStartInfo.Arguments in case you're using that overload already...

Answer (score 4):

```
Process.Start( "program.exe", "arg1 arg2 arg3" );
```