# open files by passing them to .exe

Tags: c#

I want to add audio- and video files to the playlist of a player.

This is working.

```
for (int count = 0; count < myFiles.Length; count++)
{
   process.start(myFiles[count]);
}
```

But I want to open the files with the "correct" player even it's not the default one.

So I tried this version.

```
for (int count = 0; count < myFiles.Length; count++)
{
  process.start("targetApp.exe",myFiles[count]);
}
```

The problem is that the player starts "count" instances and each with one file in the playlist.

A couple of month ago I saw an example that shows how to open files by drag&drop them to an exe-file

This would do the job. Because it works if I do this manually in the explorer.
But it was not possible to find this example again. I have in mind that it was done by dodragdrop.

---

//Edit//  (Thanks for all your answers)

I want to make it dynamic. So that you can choose the player.
But that seems with `process.start()` impossible.

It's very strange!
I've tested now three players with the same preferences.

- Allow only one instance = @1
- Allow multiple instances = @m
- MPClassic: @1 launches still "count" instances (per instance one file)
- PotPlayer: @1 if already running - nothing / if closed - only the first file
- KMPlayer:  @1 if already running - URL-Error?? / if closed - adds all files to one instance
- MPClassic: @m launches "count" instances (per instance one file)
- PotPlayer: @m launches "count" instances (per instance one file)
- KMPlayer:  @m launches "count" instances (per instance one file)

The only thing which works everywhere is when I drag&drop all files manually to the exe.

Comment: we would need more information... what player are you looking at? have considered building a playlist instead of sending each file to the exe? I have a program at home that selects random files from my music folder, and creates a WMP playlist via XML... from there i can throw that file (the playlist) over to WMP and it has all of them.

Comment: This is going to depend on targetApp's abilities. Maybe you have to start the targetApp.exe process with all files as parameters all at once. Maybe targetApp.exe doesn't support this invocation, even if it does support dragging & dropping multiple files in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass each element of `myFiles` to the app.

```
var str = "";
for(int count = 0; count < myFiles.Length; count++)
{
   str += " " + myFiles[count];
}

process.start("targetApp.exe", str);
```

There's likely going to be some issues with the formatting of `str` that you'll need to resolve, you'll also need to ensure each file gets its own encompassing quotes to ensure it's passed as an argument correctly, but this should suffice.

Example: [How to pass multiple arguments to a newly created process in C# .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464289/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-to-a-newly-created-process-in-c-sharp-net)

Comment: Come on... `string.Join(" ", myFiles);`

Comment: @AustinSalonen yes, you could do it that way, but I wanted to demonstrate the actual methodology behind it, his question was simple, so I don't think he would have benefited from just being given a method to use without knowing the underlying process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have a parameter value to set or to specify in the aim to add files into a unique playlist.

Can you detailed which application you want to use ?